# How to fix full screen size problem on debian 12 Kde plasma?

Tags: debian, kde-plasma

I'm using 2 monitors and the second one is on portrait mode. When I try to maximize the screen of an application it only extend till a spesific part of the screen as in the image. If I re-arrange the monitor positions the problem is solved for a while but then the problem occurs again after some time. Is there a perminent solution for this.
[image]

[image]